# Remove last 6 numbers from a string In MYSQL

Tags: mysql

hi i need to Remove last 6 numbers from a string , string are

HSC006783
PG000211
MPHIL000003
PHD000001

i need output like this HSC , PG ,MPHIL,PHD

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTRING(col_name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col_name) - 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT that_column, SUBSTRING(that_column, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(that_column) - 6) AS that_column_trimmed 
FROM that_table
```